# Using ngFor to create buttons with conditionally disabled status

Tags: angular, cordova, ngfor

I'm trying to create a list of buttons coming from an array using ngFor.
I was able to achieve that, however my problem is that I need to disable the buttons after certain "number" as the user has not yet reached that level.

Example of what i want to create: *(with buttons/levels disabled if not yet reached)*

[image: created button example]

**HTML File:**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
      <button class="chap_btn" id="{{'btn_'+p}}" ion-button outline *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)" [disabled]="setDisabled(p)">{{p}}</button>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**TS File:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-chapters',
  templateUrl: 'chapters.html'
})
export class ChaptersPage {
  public pages = [];
  public disabledBtn = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public glob:GlobalVariable) {
    this.pages = this.glob.chaptersBtn; // contains the number of LEVELS
    alert(this.pages)
  }

  setDisabled(p){
    if(p == this.glob.globalLevel.userLevel || p < 
this.glob.globalLevel.userLevel)
    {
     return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
   }


  openPage(p){
    this.navCtrl.push(LevelsPage, {
      level: p
    });
  }
```

How can I set the buttons to become disabled when the "p" *(number)* exceeds the user level?

Thank you

Comment: `<button [disabled]="p > glob.hlobalLevel.userLevel">`?

Comment: That worked thanks a lot!

Comment: I've posted that as an answer then. Mark it as an answer to this question please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `disabled` attribute based on condition like this:

```
<button [disabled]="p > glob.hlobalLevel.userLevel">
```